# iphone - Can't find the "developer" tab after updating to iOS 5.1

Tags: iphone, ios5.1

I need to activate the loggin on the iphone, but after updating the iOS I can't seem to find the "developer" tab to activate it.

Any idea? Am I blind?

Comment: Really should be asked on http://apple.stackexchange.com/ not here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activate your iPhone for development in Xcode.